# MySQL doesn't start on Ubuntu 22.04; unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm facing an issue with installing MySQL server on Ubuntu 22.04. When I try to start the MySQL service using the command sudo service mysql start, I get the following error message

The error message suggests a configuration error in the server. Can you guide me through the correct steps to successfully start the MySQL server? Thank you."
Knowing that I still haven't linked my hosting to my domain

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-07-17 01:55:02 UTC; 9ms ago
    Process: 348248 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 82ms

Jul 17 01:55:02 server1.elhodhod.ma mysql-systemd-start[348248]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Jul 17 01:55:02 server1.elhodhod.ma mysql-systemd-start[348248]: 2023-07-17  1:55:02 0 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
Jul 17 01:55:02 server1.elhodhod.ma mysql-systemd-start[348248]: Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Jul 17 01:55:02 server1.elhodhod.ma mysql-systemd-start[348248]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service.
Jul 17 01:55:02 server1.elhodhod.ma systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 17 01:55:02 server1.elhodhod.ma systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 01:55:02 server1.elhodhod.ma systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: the variable is `mysqlx_bind_address` - the command line format is `--mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1` - I suspect you've conflated the two

Comment: Are you back on-line?

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable `mysqlx-bind-address` defined in your MySQL configuration files which your version of MySQL doesn't understand and this prevents it from starting. You need to remove this variable and review your configuration files so that it matches the version of MySQL you have installed.